# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate is incompatible on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I just got a new Windows 8 laptop, and one of the first things I installed was Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. Once it was done, I opened it up, and I am getting this:

[image]

I have tried clicking both buttons (Get help online and Run the program without getting help), and neither work. Although, I don't understand why it is having compatibility issues when I had this same program on a W8 laptop before I got a new one. I have heard that installing an update will do it but I can't even start up VS to get to the Tools > Extensions > Check for updates. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Please install update  4 in order to get rid of that message.
You can download it from here :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39305

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll let you know if it works once it's done downloading. (Pretty big file)